# Make a whole table a link

Tags: html, css

I have 3 tables and I want each table to be a link. This works pretty good so far, but for some reason I can't round the corners anymore afterwards.

This is what I want it to look like: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vRP63/2/

Here I tried to add links to each table:
http://jsfiddle.net/vRP63/1/

What is wrong with this:

```
<a href="google.com">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>def</td>
        <td>ghi</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</a>
```

By the way, I could get it work using onClick events. But I don't want to use any Javascript for this.

Answer (score 2):

Because each table is now the first of type in it's parent (`<a>`).
So you need to target the `<a>` as the first and last of type:

```
a:first-of-type table {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
a:last-of-type table {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vRP63/4/

Comment: 1+ Nice one. I was seconds away from posting the exact solution.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/ysrsR/

Comment: @JoshC - It's normally the other way round, can't count how many times I've started answering only to see your answer pop up :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your content inside a parent element

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

than do: http://jsfiddle.net/vRP63/5/

```
.parent a:first-of-type table {
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
.parent a:last-of-type table {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
}
```

Additionally you might want to put `http://` in your `href`s :)